# How to manage multiple 'minigames' inside one application/game using Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have developed an application that is also a game and therefore I have decided to make use of online multiplayer and register it with Google Play Game Services. After developing the first minigame, everything is working as expected and I am not coming across any issues. When developing the second minigame, I suddenly wondered how would I be able to uniquely allow my users to play multiplayer games on a specific minigame?

The application is linked to a game service which then provides me with an APP_ID that exists in my manifest file like so:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

It would seem to make sense that I could create multiple game services and link them all to my application. However how would I then be able to handle multiple APP_IDs in the application? When I use the `GoogleApiClient`, it simply utilises the APP_ID from the manifest and I cannot specify a specific APP_ID game service to launch and provide a connection to Google Play Games and Google+:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

Is there a best practice to tackle multiple games inside one application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found out that you can specify a `variant` value which is an `int` from the value of 1 to 1023. When building a room, you can set this variant to the appropriate `int` to reflect a different game type:

```
RoomConfig.Builder selectPlayersRoomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
selectPlayersRoomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
// specifies a specific game variant
selectPlayersRoomConfigBuilder.setVariant(gameType);
if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
    selectPlayersRoomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
}

// prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, selectPlayersRoomConfigBuilder.build());
```

With my game example, `gameType` is an int that is set from the previous `Activity` when the user chooses which game they would like to play and is then passed in through the `Intent`. I have decided on using 1 for the first game type and 2 for the second game type etc.